# Send Order Confirmation email notification in WooCommerce thankyou

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I need to send the order confirmation E-Mail within Woocommerce to the store owner via a php function.
I want to hook it to the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', '####', 55 );
```

But I don't know which funktion to call to fire the email? The E-Mail template is stored in the following directory and is called: woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php
Could you help me with this?

If you need any more details please leave a comment!
Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id){
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}, 55 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

> **Since WooCommerce 5+:** [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)